# Literature: Derivations in C*-Algebras

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, banach-spaces, banach-algebras

Do you have some nice reference for dynamical systems in C*-algebras (including discussion of their derivations!) like notes, papers, books, etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try S. Sakai, "[Operator Algebras in Dynamical Systems](http://books.google.ca/books?id=fgYPJyqBBwUC)".

Comment: Thanks! :) Does it also include a section on the one-to-one correspondence between derivations and dynamical systems?